# Cuales serian los primeros pasos para realizar este programa en c++ MultiHilo?

Tags: c++, hilos

Usted ha sido contratado por la Madre Naturaleza para ayudarla con la reacción química para formar agua. Ella tiene dificultades para generarla debido a problemas de sincronización. El truco consiste en tener 2 átomos de H y 1 átomo de O, todos al mismo tiempo. Los átomos son threads y puede haber varios O y otros tantos H. Cada átomo llama al procedimiento naturaleza_o_listo y naturaleza_h_listo , cuando cada uno esta listo para reaccionar. Se supone que eventualmente todo átomo estará listo para reaccionar.
Los procesos que ejecutan los átomos-hilos serían:

```
void abstraccion_o(void) {
        //solo soy un O calmo
        naturaleza_o_listo(n);
    }
    void abstraccion_h(void) {
        //solo soy un O calmo
        naturaleza_h_listo(n); _Y;
    }
```

Los procedimientos naturaleza_o_listo y naturaleza_h_listo , deberían incrementar la cantidad de átomos listos para reaccionar de cada tipo en la naturaleza y cuando se junte la cantidad necesaria, uno de ellos debería llamar a la función naturaleza_hacer_agua , que simplemente imprime un mensaje y deja que estos átomos terminen, pues ya forman parte de una molécula y no son capaces de reaccionar de ahora en más.
Al finalizar se deberían tener todos las posibles moléculas de agua armadas y los átomos restantes esperando y listos para reaccionar.

Se deberán crear el tipo de dato abstracto naturaleza que será una abstracción de ella, donde además de llevarse la cuenta de la cantidad de átomos de H y O listos para reaccionar se incluyan las variables de sincronización que se consideren necesarias (locks, semáforos y variables de condición).

Answer (score 0):

Una posibilidad es crear un TAD naturaleza que inicialmente tenga 2 componentes, más todas
las de sincronización que se pudieran agregar, junto a las funciones que operan sobre ese TAD.

```
    struct naturaleza_s {
    nat h_listo,o_listo;
    };
    typedef struct naturaleza_s*
    naturaleza;
    naturaleza naturaleza_crear(void);
    void naturaleza_destruir(naturaleza
    n);
    void naturaleza_o_listo(naturaleza 
    n);
    void naturaleza_h_listo(naturaleza 
    n);
    void 
    naturaleza_hacer_agua(naturaleza
    n);
    void naturaleza_a_cadena(naturaleza 
    n,
    char* buffer);
```

Las funciones naturaleza_o_listo y naturaleza_h_listo simplemente incrementan los escalares en el TAD y
deberían sincronizarse de manera que tan pronto como haya H2O, se llame a naturaleza_hacer_agua , que tiene
como precondición

2<=n->h_listo & 1<=n->o_listo

para que luego de los decrementos que implican la formación del agua, los escalares sigan siendo de tipo Nat.
Claramente si la sincronización resulta correcta siempre se dará la precondición de naturaleza_hacer_agua.